How do I use Object Layers from Tiled Maps using Python Arcade
I'm creating a basic game using Python Arcade and Tiled Map Editor. My problem is, I can't use the Object Layer in arcade in their built-in Physics Engine. I can see, after creating an instance of the tiled map the layers are separated into Tile Layers and Object Layers, but arcade.PhysicsEngineSimple() doesn't use the object layers. This means I can't have collisions into walls or set a starting position for my player and enemies.
I asked a similar question before: Unable to use Object Layer from a Tiled Map with Python Arcade, which involved creating a Tile Layer called "Walls" and using "use_spatial_hash": True, but after using the solution, I realized that this still only uses the Tile Layer and doesn't work for what I want. The collisions work, but it will be set to the size of the tile (In my case 64X64) but if I want a collision boundary that is thin and long then it won't work.

If anyone has any experience with handling Object Layers in Python Arcade, your help will be greatly appreciated.
It is very basic code at the moment, as I'm just learning arcade.
My code can be found here: Basic Dungeon Game
I am using arcade version 3.0.0dev32

There is no built-in functionality to support Object Layers in Arcade. So you need to write your own. For example you can use following approach:

Read Object Layer data from tilemap
Generate Sprite with the Object Layer coordinates
Add Sprite to Walls Sprite list


Below is your updated code:
import arcade

from game_sprites import Player

SCALE = 3
PLAYER_MOVEMENT_SPEED = 7


class Game(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera = None
        self.tile_map = None
        map_name = "maps/dungeon.tmx"
        layer_options = {'Bricks': {'use_spatial_hash': True}}
        self.tile_map = arcade.load_tilemap(map_name, SCALE, layer_options)
        player_position = self.tile_map.object_lists["Sprite Positions"][0].properties

        # Get object layer
        points = self.tile_map.object_lists['Walls'][0].shape
        width = abs(points[0][0] - points[1][0])
        height = abs(points[0][1] - points[2][1])
        center_x = points[0][0] + width/2
        center_y = points[0][1] - height/2
        wall = arcade.SpriteSolidColor(width, height, center_x, center_y, arcade.color.RED)

        self.scene = arcade.Scene.from_tilemap(self.tile_map)
        walls = self.scene['Bricks']
        walls.append(wall)

        self.player = Player(center_x=player_position["X"]*SCALE, center_y=player_position["Y"]*SCALE, scale=1)
        self.player_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.player_list.append(self.player)
        self.physics_engine = arcade.PhysicsEngineSimple(self.player, walls=walls)
        self.camera_sprites = arcade.camera.Camera2D()
        self.left_pressed = False
        self.right_pressed = False
        self.up_pressed = False
        self.down_pressed = False

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.camera_sprites.use()
        self.scene.draw()
        self.player_list.draw()

    def on_update(self, delta_time):
        self.physics_engine.update()
        self.player.update_animation()
        self.player.change_x = 0
        self.player.change_y = 0

        # self.player.coll

        if self.up_pressed and not self.down_pressed:
            self.player.change_y = PLAYER_MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif self.down_pressed and not self.up_pressed:
            self.player.change_y = -PLAYER_MOVEMENT_SPEED
        if self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:
            self.player.change_x = -PLAYER_MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:
            self.player.change_x = PLAYER_MOVEMENT_SPEED

        self.scroll_to_player()

    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):

        if key == arcade.key.UP:
            self.up_pressed = True
        elif key == arcade.key.DOWN:
            self.down_pressed = True
        elif key == arcade.key.LEFT:
            self.left_pressed = True
        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.right_pressed = True

    def on_key_release(self, key, modifiers):

        if key == arcade.key.UP:
            self.up_pressed = False
        elif key == arcade.key.DOWN:
            self.down_pressed = False
        elif key == arcade.key.LEFT:
            self.left_pressed = False
        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.right_pressed = False

    def scroll_to_player(self):
        position = (self.player.center_x, self.player.center_y)
        self.camera_sprites.position = arcade.math.lerp_2d(self.camera_sprites.position, position, 0.1)


Game()
arcade.run()


Thank you again! I've been trying to get this working and couldn't think of how to do it but It's working exactly how I want it to. You are a genius.
